# insert list into table: cassandra

Tags: sql, cassandra, nosql

How can i insert something like this in cassandra:

```
{
    "custID" : '12736467',
    "date" : '2013-06-10',
    "orderID" : 19482065,
    "amount" : 216.28,
    "items" : [
        {   "id" : 1
            "sku" : 87482734,
            "quantity" : 4
        },
        {    "id":2
            "sku" : 32851042,
            "quantity" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I thought the best way to store this data in cassandra is to create one table with family column:

```
custId   | date     | orderID | amount | items
                                        id | sku     | quantity
12736467 2013-06-10  19482065  216.28   1   87482734  4
                                        2   32851042  2

create table items {
id text,
sku int,
quantity int};

create table test  {
  custId   text,
  date bigint,
  orderId text,
  amount float,
  items list<items >,
  PRIMARY KEY ((custId))
};
```

but how can I do insert into this table without using update for each time (insert into test ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a table, it is better to create a User Defined Type.

Then use the following:

```
INSERT INTO items ("custId", date, "orderId", amount, items)
       VALUES ( 'custid', 123456, 'orderid', 10.0, 
                [ { 'id' : '1', 'sku' : 12345, 'quantity' : 4 },
                  { 'id' : '2', 'sku' : 12345, 'quantity' : 2 }]);
```